# Help Getting More Info Out of Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I am getting the following failure from one of my tests.

```
Failures:

  1) InstrumentController POST create with valid params creates a new Instrument
     Failure/Error: expect {
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/instrument_controller_spec.rb:63:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have double checked all of my validations on the model class and cannot find Any reason why this might be failing.  Is there a way to get more information logged out from Rspec, or does anyone clearly see where i've gone wrong here?

Thank you for your time.  Below is the source for my factories and tests:

```
# spec/factories.rb
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  # Sequences
  sequence :email do |n|
    "email#{n}@factory.com"
  end

  sequence :instrumentmeaningsid do |n|
    n
  end


  # Roles
  factory :admin_role, :class => Role do
    name 'Admin'
  end

  factory :user_role, :class => Role do
    name 'User'
  end


  # Users
  factory :admin_user, :class => User do
    email 'admin@test.com'
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    name 'Andy McAdmin'
    roles { |a| [a.association(:admin_role)] }
  end

  factory :user, :class => User do
    email
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    name 'Yuri Userington'
    roles { |a| [a.association(:user_role)] } #many to many
  end


  # Instruments
  factory :instrument, :class => Instrument do
    title "Doobie Doo Instrument Title"
    is_valid true
    association :user
    instrumentmeaningsid
  end

end
```

.

```
# spec/controllers/instruments_controller_spec.rb
describe InstrumentsController do

  describe "POST create" do

    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Instrument" do
        expect {
          post :create, :instrument => Factory.build(:instrument, :user => Factory(:user)).attributes
        }.to change(Instrument, :count).by(1)
      end
    end

   end

end
```

Edit: added the Instrument controller per apneadiving's request:

```
# app/controllers/instruments_controller.rb
class InstrumentsController < ApplicationController
  # CanCan
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /instruments
  # GET /instruments.json
  def index
    @instruments = Instrument.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @instruments }
    end
  end

  # GET /instruments/new
  # GET /instruments/new.json
  def new
    @instrument = Instrument.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json
    end
  end

  # GET /instruments/1/edit
  def edit
    @instrument = Instrument.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /instruments
  # POST /instruments.json
  def create
    @instrument = Instrument.new(params[:instrument])
    @instrument.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @instrument.save
        format.html { redirect_to @instrument, notice: 'Instrument was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @instrument, status: :created, location: @instrument }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @instrument.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /instruments/1
  # PUT /instruments/1.json
  def update
    @instrument = Instrument.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @instrument.update_attributes(params[:instrument])
        format.html { redirect_to @instrument, notice: 'Instrument was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @instrument.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /instruments/1
  # DELETE /instruments/1.json
  def destroy
    @instrument = Instrument.find(params[:id])
    @instrument.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to instruments_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the actual content of the spec that is failing, and maybe your model's applicable validation code as well?

Comment: you should post your song spec.

Comment: Sorry guys. I accidentally copied the wrong failure output. The failure has been updated (this pertains to Instrument).  The spec's source is located under the factory source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your factory is building a valid instrument? Try adding

```
Factory.build(:instrument).should be_valid
```

To your specs.